# What is the new "low quality" threshold?

Tags: support, flagging, automatic-flagging

I was used to the threshold for a low quality post being 80, but in recent automatically flagged posts I read "Low answer quality score [90]."

What is the new threshold value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 3 cases where the score is ignored and posts are flagged anyway provided the post is shorter than **220** chars.

1. The answer contains "thank|cheers|thx|great" ..
2. The answer contains "same.*?(problem|error|bug)"
3. The answer is a single URL

Comment: Thank you. This helps in understanding what should be done to improve the answers flagged as low quality.